# Poisson counting process subinterval distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, queueing

Suppose $N(t)$ is a [homogeneous Poisson counting process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_counting_process) with a constant parameter $\lambda$. Given positive real numbers $T$ and $\tau$, and non-negative integer $n$, what is the probability that $N(t)$ counts exactly $n$ points within at least one subinterval $[t,t+\tau]$ of $[0,T]$, or Prob$\big(\bigcup_t\big\{N(t)\,\big|\, [t,t+\tau]\subseteq [0,T] \wedge N(t+\tau)-N(t)=n\big\}\big)$?

Someone has suggested the rejection question in the queueing theory may consider such problems. But I have not found the exact literature.